# Web Sockets Error message in console when not using web sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, azure

Why would I get a web sockets error message appearing in a browser console when I'm not (knowingly/intentionally) using web sockets?

My system comprises a React client, a Node backend and a MYSQL database which interact over https.  The client and server are running as separate web services on Azure and the database is hosted on Azure.

Error: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://my-frontend-url:300/ws.`.

The error message links to a Javascript file called WebSocketClient.js which isn't a file I created or configured, so guess it is part of Node or React, perhaps.

Comment: Could be one of 1: A browser add-on, or 2: some hot reloading modules. If it's 2 and you see this in production you might be running some dev build.

Comment: I've tested and ruled out #1, but #2 seems likely.  I did the production build in VS Code then deployed that to Azure direct from VSCode.  The local folder I selected for deployment was the one containing the build folder, but also containing all of the other JavaScript folders/files.  
I set NODE-ENV=production in the Application Settings config screen on Azure, and added the following code in Start-up Commands in the General Settings config screen: pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build/ --no-daemon. I'm still not sure it has deployed the production build though - do you know how I can check?